Why is Maven breaking my Eclipse project and how do I fix this?
Is there some sort of comprehensive guide for Maven and Eclipse that I'm just unaware of? I understand there is an option to disable project configuration updating from pom.xml, but I'd rather put in the work to have my project just work fresh from git.
I am trying to upgrade my project from Java 8 to Java 17. Somewhere along the line, Maven has started "misbehaving". When I update my project, it adds folders (src/test, target/generated-test-sources) I don't need. It adds a .factorypath configuration I don't want. It edits my build configuration so that every time I try to move to a different setting I'm asked to save or discard some change that I have no clue as to what it pertains. And right now, it's telling me that all jakarta.enterprise.* imports are invalid, when I have the dependency in my POM, and I can see the specific classes I need in the Project Explorer under Maven dependencies.
Please look over my pom, point out any glaring errors, and please, make it make sense!
Here is the pom for my project:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>my.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp_ocp</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../myapp_ocp/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>myapp_ejb</artifactId>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <name>myapp_ejb</name>
    <description />
    <dependencies>
        <!-- JAXB API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JAXB Runtime Implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamicreports-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Provided dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.20.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>
                        hibernate-commons-annotations
                    </artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-full-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/main/resources/full-jar.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-domain-remote-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>
                                    src/main/resources/domain-remote-jar.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.2</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-ejb</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>ejb</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

And here is the effective pom
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>my.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp_ocp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../myapp_ocp/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <groupId>my.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>myapp_ejb</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>ejb</packaging>
  <name>myapp_ejb</name>
  <description></description>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jboss.xp.galleon.feature.pack.version>4.0.0.GA-redhat-00014</jboss.xp.galleon.feature.pack.version>
    <project.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</project.version>
    <bootable.jar.maven.plugin.version>6.1.3.Final-redhat-00001</bootable.jar.maven.plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>my.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp_ejb</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>my.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>my.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp_ejb_ear</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ear</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.18.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
      <artifactId>dynamicreports-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.11.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.20.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
          <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.4.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>jboss-enterprise-maven-repository</id>
      <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>C:\Users\me\git\myapp\myapp_ejb\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>C:\Users\me\git\myapp\myapp_ejb\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>C:\Users\me\git\myapp\myapp_ejb\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>C:\Users\me\git\myapp\myapp_ejb\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>C:\Users\me\git\myapp\myapp_ejb\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>C:\Users\me\git\myapp\myapp_ejb\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>C:\Users\me\git\myapp\myapp_ejb\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>C:\Users\me\git\myapp\myapp_ejb\target</directory>
    <finalName>myapp_ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.6.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.6.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.1</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-jar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.3.Final-redhat-00001</version>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-full-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/main/resources/full-jar.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>make-domain-remote-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/main/resources/domain-remote-jar.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>17</source>
              <target>17</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>17</source>
              <target>17</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <source>17</source>
          <target>17</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-ejb</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>ejb</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <ejbVersion>3.2</ejbVersion>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <ejbVersion>3.2</ejbVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\Users\me\git\myapp\myapp_ejb\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\Users\me\git\myapp\myapp_ejb\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>C:\Users\me\git\myapp\myapp_ejb\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>C:\Users\me\git\myapp\myapp_ejb\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>

Thank you.

Which jar has those missing jakarta.enterprise.* packages and classes? Have you seen them with your own eyes?

jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api-2.0.2.jar. It has the path to it in my .m2 repository. I can see the package/class I'm trying to import, and if I double-click on it, I can see the source code.

What's the exact error message? Is there a module-info.java file present that you didn't intend to have?

The error is in my java file. 'import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;' has the 'jakarta.enterprise' highlighted and says "The import jakarta.enterprise cannot be resolved." and of course the ApplicationScoped annotation is also showing an error. No module-info.java files (which could be a problem) as I'm starting the upgrade process by updating my poms to match the java version and updating dependencies to match.
I did figure out the annotation processing. Happens when dependencies contain annotation classes. Can disable it using the none in the compiler plugin.

Isn't that the old Java EE version of the jar with the old javax package name?

Probably? I'm a BSIT who became the lead developer for a legacy Java webapp. I added Maven, upgraded from 8 to 17, and used a bootable jar for containerization in an ADO build pipeline. I inherited the project I'm working on now, which has an ejb, an ear, and a war. The admin who containerized it, I think just threw the ear and war on an image. So far, I've added a parent project to create the ejb, add it and the war to the ear, and deploy the ear in a bootable jar. I'd prefer to use the same base image as the other project, so when FYQ1 arrives we have a proper build pipeline in place.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I see. The inclusion of Log4j2 in Maven triggered the enabling of annotation processing, which created the .factorypath files to populate Project->Properties->Java Compiler->Annotation Processing->Factory Path. Adding the none element to the maven-compiler-plugin configuration disabled this, allowing my classes to see the jar in my Maven dependencies.
